# Redirecting part of URL in Nginx

Tags: redirect, nginx

Trying to move my blog to a new site and I want to redirect some urls. I use nginx.

> `https://blogurl.com/news/2014-08-19/post-3451/mt-preview-33e2742af1eb.php`

The `/news/2014-08-19/post-3451/mt-preview-33e2742af1eb.php` part would be always moving.

Redirect to below:

> `https://blogurl.com/content/news/2014-08-19/post-3451/mt-preview-33e2742af1eb.php`

I basically want to insert `/content/` after `https://blogurl.com` and so far I have

```
rewrite ^(.*)$ /content/ break;
```

But my issue is my CMS sits on the same directory level

```
https://blogurl.com/mt/admin
```

and if I simply apply the rewrite above my CMS address would move too. How could I prevent this.

Comment: Is all the content you want to move under `https://blogurl.com/news/` ?

Comment: @Hpatoio All the content is under `https://blogurl.com/content/` and CMS is under `https://blogurl.com/mt/`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your rewrite rule to:

`rewrite ^(?!\/mt)(.*)$ /content$1 break;`

That should add `/content` to all URLs that do not start with `mt`

Comment: It didn't work.  URL with /mt/ becomes Not Found but redirect of /content works fine.

Comment: Do you have other rewrite ? Set `error_log` to `debug` to see if/how URL beginning with `mt` are rewritten.

Comment: I've updated the regexp. Let me know if is working now. If not enable the `debug`, as I said in the previous comment, and let me know.

Comment: sorry for late response. yes and no. on your first answer I had to edit as `rewrite ^(?!/mt/)(.*)$` but way you revised should work too.